# how to make array of array by looping result from a query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a survey about games, and I have one table for the games data, and another for people's answers.

I want to output an array in Json format for answers with each of the 3 favorite games name and their year in an array of array.

**expected output**

```
[
    {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "userX",
    "g1": {"name": "game1", "year": "1991"},
    "g2": {"name": "game2", "year": "1992"},
    "g3": {"name": "game3", "year": "1993"},
    }
]
```

**what i've tried**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbAnswers AS answer INNER JOIN tbgames AS game ON answer.g1 = game.id";

try {
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    $answer = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $db = null;

    if(empty($answer)) {
        $response->getBody()->write
        ('
        {
            "error":
            {
                "status":"400",
                "message":"Invalid Request"
            }
        }');
    } else {
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($answer));
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $response->getBody()->write
    ('
    {
        "error":
        {
            "message":'. $e->getMessage() .'
        }
    }');
}
```

**the current output**

```
[
    {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "userX",
    "name": "game1",
    "year": "1991"
    }
]
```

I think i should do a foreach somewhere in else to go through each game and echo the result of it based on the id from answers, but i am not sure how to apply it

1. where to place to foreach
2. how to select and get the results based on each game id
3. how to do it in json format

i'm sure it's not how i am doing it, this is how i am trying to echo the data in else

```
echo"[";
echo"\n{";
echo"\n";
echo '"id:"'.' "'.$answer[0]->id.'",';
echo"\n";
echo"}\n";
echo"]";
```

here are my tables structure

**tbGames**

```
    id   ,  name    ,  year
     1   , 'game1'  , '1991'
     2   , 'game2'  , '1992'
     3   , 'game3'  , '1993'
     4   , 'game4'  , '1994'
```

**tbAnswers**

```
   id   ,    name    ,    g1    ,   g2    ,   g3
    1   ,    userX   ,    1     ,   2     ,    3  
    2   ,    userY   ,    3     ,   1     ,    4
    3   ,    userZ   ,    1     ,   1     ,    2
    4   ,    userW   ,    2     ,   3     ,    4
```

Comment: first, your sql query should be something like this: 
SELECT * 
FROM tbAnswers AS answer 
INNER JOIN tbgames AS game1 ON answer.g1 = game1.id
INNER JOIN tbgames AS game2 ON answer.g2 = game2.id
INNER JOIN tbgames AS game3 ON answer.g3 = game3.id

Comment: You need to change your query instead of `answer.g1` use `answer.id` this must be get the data you need

Comment: @perodriguezl can you tell me where to place to foreach
how to select and get the results based on each game id
how to do it in json format

Comment: replace your SQL query with this $sql = "SELECT answer.id a_id, answer.name a_name,
    game1.id g1_id, game1.name g1_name, game1.year g1_year,
    game2.id g2_id, game2.name g2_name, game2.year g2_year,
    game3.id g3_id, game3.name g3_name, game3.year g3_year
    FROM tbAnswers AS answer 
    INNER JOIN tbgames AS game1 ON answer.g1 = game1.id 
    INNER JOIN tbgames AS game2 ON answer.g2 = game2.id 
    INNER JOIN tbgames AS game3 ON answer.g3 = game3.id"; and show the new (FULL) output

Comment: @perodriguezl i did try that before, it shows the same output as the current output that i posted in my question, even though i added all the inner joins

Comment: I can help you but you have to collaborate, you will never get that data with that query you posted!

Comment: @perodriguezl oh im sorry, i thought it was what i tried did not notice that u allocated names for each field, thats what i got 
`[
    {
    "a_id": "1",
    "a_name": "userX", 
    "g1_id": "1", 
    "g1_name": "game1",  
    "g1_year": "1991", 
    "g2_id": "2", 
    "g2_name": "game2",  
    "g2_year": "1992", 
    "g3_id": "3", 
    "g3_name": "game3",  
    "g3_year": "1993"
    }
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT answer.id a_id, answer.name a_name, game1.id g1_id, game1.name g1_name, game1.year g1_year, game2.id g2_id, game2.name g2_name, game2.year g2_year, game3.id g3_id, game3.name g3_name, game3.year g3_year FROM tbAnswers AS answer INNER JOIN tbgames AS game1 ON answer.g1 = game1.id INNER JOIN tbgames AS game2 ON answer.g2 = game2.id INNER JOIN tbgames AS game3 ON answer.g3 = game3.id";
```

you should change your else statement content to:

```
} else {
    foreach($answer as $value) {
        $array_resp[]=[
            'id' => $value->a_id,
            'username' => $value->a_name,
            'g1' => ['name'=>$value->g1_name, 'year'=>$value->g1_year],
            'g2' => ['name'=>$value->g2_name, 'year'=>$value->g2_year],
            'g3' => ['name'=>$value->g3_name, 'year'=>$value->g3_year],
            ];
    }
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($array_resp));
}
```

Comment: your answer makes a lot of sense, but i am getting this error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: yes, you are right, you should try with the modification I Aplied, @mirvatJ

Comment: now i get Cannot use object of type Slim\Http\Response as array

Comment: @mirvatJ change the $response var name to $array_resp

Comment: i figured that one out by now :p your amazing @perodriguezl thank you so much for your help!!